# Как безопасно добавить базу данных на сайт?

Tags: php, mysql

Я хочу добавить базу данных на сайт, но для того, чтобы это сделать в `.php` файле я должен вставить, допустим, такой пример кода:

```
$servername = "test.co.uk";
$database = "u266072517_name";
$username = "u266072517_user";
$password = "buystuffpwd";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Меня лишь беспокоит то, что я вставляю логин и пароль к базе данных. Как мне правильно записать подключение к БД, чтобы мой логин и пароль не перехватили? Может стоит как-то в отдельных файлах все записать?

Я создаю сайт на web-hosting'е

Comment: Ваш код полностью нормальный, логин и пароль находятся в переменных которые пользователи сайта не могут видеть. Таким образом на всех сайтах идет подключения к базе данных

Comment: @Arendach то есть, предположим, хакер не сможет взять данные из этих переменны?

Comment: @Antonio112009 Пароли к БД вас не сильно должны волновать. Если взломает сервер - то получит доступ ко всему. А взломать он его сможет если не будете уделять должное внимание безопасности при написании своего кода....

Comment: @Manitikyl отчасти в этом и состоит вопрос... Как правильно записывать это? Я читал, что создаешь, к примеру `app_conf.php` -  в нем пишешь константы с данными к БД и сохраняешь этот файл на одну и более папку выше, чем корень сайта

Comment: Далее создаешь `database.php` и в нем с помощью `require_one` обращаешься к `app_conf.php` и в нем пишешь подключение к БД, а после вызываешь `database.php` на нужных тебе страницах сайта. Данные действия они правильные? + У меня юзер имеет полные права по использованию БД... Надо будет потом какие-то права убрать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как правильно записывать это? Я читал, что создаешь, к примеру
>   app_conf.php - в нем пишешь константы с данными к БД и сохраняешь этот
>   файл на одну и более папку выше, чем корень сайта

Если вопрос в этом, то ответ можно дать:

**Во-первых**, хочу подчеркнуть: нет такого: правильно или нет, вы как программист должны в первую очередь уметь обосновать почему именно ТАК, а не как иначе. Поэтому я постараюсь дать объяснение почему так, а не как иначе.

Предположим что у нас есть такая условная директория:

```
../www/mysite.ru/
```

В этой папке мы размещаем наши файлы проекта, но у такого подхода есть минус:

**Например** если есть файл конфигурации, предположим ваш `app_conf.php` который лежит в папке `config`, т.е. полный путь `../www/mysite.ru/config/app_conf.php` то к нему можно обратить внешне, т.е. через браузер: `mysite.ru/config/app_conf.php`. Да, вы с помощью вебсервера можете запретить доступ в этому файлу, но это уже плохо (по ряду причин), и плюс для сайта потерян урл такого вида. Поэтому традиционно немного разделяют - то что для пользователя и то что системное, условно так:

```
[wwww]
    [mysite.ru]
        [config]
            app_conf.php
        [public]
            index.php
```

Как видите, у нас есть папка `public` которая содержит только то, что нужно *видеть* пользователю, там дизайн (стили скрипты), картинки, и прочее, НО всегда есть один файл, в нашем случае `index.php` - который является точкой входа для генерации динамических страниц. Вот он уже обращается к `config/app.conf.php` и т.д. Как вы видите, да, системные файлы (т.е. те файлы которые не нужны для пользователя, выносятся на уровень выше).

Такая структура конечно выигрывает во всем, у нее нет минусов перед структурой где все в кучке. К скриптам прямого доступа нет, веб-сервер лишними проверками нагружать не надо, выглядит все более менее логично и понятно, НО я хочу подчеркнуть то что писал в комментарии:

> ...А взломать он его сможет если не будете уделять должное внимание
>   безопасности при написании своего кода...

Это я писал к тому, что перед злоумышленником не будет разницы как у вас расположены файлы и в каких директориях если он сможет выполнять `php-скрипты`. Ну как банальный детский пример, у вас есть загрузка файлов, он загружает туда файл с расширением php --> получает путь --> обращается к нему --> php-скрипт выполняется (да такое тоже защищается веб сервером, на все есть ответ, но все-же просто для примера). Возвращаясь к нашему примеру: для хацкера не будет разницы где у вас там файлы расположены он все равно получит к ним доступ.

**Перехватить** на каком-то там лету не получится в обоих случаях, но если получить доступ к сайту - получить он сможет все. Поэтому уделите особое внимание безопасности.